# Application not launch on simulator in iOS and React-native

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, launching-application

When, I run application on simulator iPhone 8 , simulator is launching but application is not running and stuck on black screen with apple logo. But, If i used physical device then its work fine.

I have already tried following solution

1.
- Clear derived data 
- Kill Xcode and simulator 
- restart Xcode and run project on simulator

2.
- Hardware-> Erase all content and Setting... 
- restart simulator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjqqD.png)

Answer (score 0):

There will be build folder in your react native project directory. 
Delete this folder once and rebuild the project.